# CASE in WHERE Clause in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to do a case statement within the where clause in snowflake but I’m not quite sure how should I go about doing it.

What I’m trying to do is, if my current month is Jan, then the where clause for date is between start of previous year and today. If not, the where clause for date would be between start of current year and today.

```
WHERE 
CASE MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) = 1 THEN DATE BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(‘YEAR’, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CURRENT_DATE())) AND CURRENT_DATE()
CASE MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) != 1 THEN DATE BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(‘YEAR’, CURRENT_DATE()) AND CURRENT_DATE()
END
```

Appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you don't even need to use `CASE` here:

```sql
WHERE
    (MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) = 1 AND
     DATE BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(‘YEAR’, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, CURRENT_DATE())) AND
                  CURRENT_DATE()) OR
    (MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) != 1 AND
     DATE BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(‘YEAR’, CURRENT_DATE()) AND CURRENT_DATE())
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `CASE` expression that returns `-1` if the current month is January or `0` for any other month, so that you can get with `DATEADD()` a date of the previous or the current year to use in `DATE_TRUNC()`:

```
WHERE DATE BETWEEN 
        DATE_TRUNC('YEAR', DATEADD(YEAR, CASE WHEN MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) = 1 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END, CURRENT_DATE())) 
        AND 
        CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

So the other answers are quite good, but... the answer can be even simpler

Making a little table to brake down what is happening.

```sql
select 
    row_number() over (order by null) - 1 as rn, 
    dateadd('day', rn * 5, date_trunc('year',current_date())) as pretend_current_date,
    DATEADD(YEAR, -1, pretend_current_date) as pcd_sub1,
    month(pretend_current_date) as pcd_month,
    DATE_TRUNC(year, iff(pcd_month = 1, pcd_sub1, pretend_current_date)) as _from,
    pretend_current_date as _to
from table(generator(ROWCOUNT => 30))
order by rn;
```

this shows:

| RN | PRETEND_CURRENT_DATE | PCD_SUB1 | PCD_MONTH | _FROM | _TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-01 | 2021-01-01 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | 2021-01-06 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-06 |
| 2 | 2022-01-11 | 2021-01-11 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-11 |
| 3 | 2022-01-16 | 2021-01-16 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-16 |
| 4 | 2022-01-21 | 2021-01-21 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-21 |
| 5 | 2022-01-26 | 2021-01-26 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-26 |
| 6 | 2022-01-31 | 2021-01-31 | 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |
| 7 | 2022-02-05 | 2021-02-05 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-05 |
| 8 | 2022-02-10 | 2021-02-10 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-10 |
| 9 | 2022-02-15 | 2021-02-15 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-15 |
| 10 | 2022-02-20 | 2021-02-20 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-20 |
| 11 | 2022-02-25 | 2021-02-25 | 2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-25 |
| 12 | 2022-03-02 | 2021-03-02 | 3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-02 |
| 13 | 2022-03-07 | 2021-03-07 | 3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-07 |
| 14 | 2022-03-12 | 2021-03-12 | 3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-12 |
| 15 | 2022-03-17 | 2021-03-17 | 3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-17 |
| 16 | 2022-03-22 | 2021-03-22 | 3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-22 |
| 17 | 2022-03-27 | 2021-03-27 | 3 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-03-27 |
| 18 | 2022-04-01 | 2021-04-01 | 4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-01 |
| 19 | 2022-04-06 | 2021-04-06 | 4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-06 |
| 20 | 2022-04-11 | 2021-04-11 | 4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-11 |
| 21 | 2022-04-16 | 2021-04-16 | 4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-16 |
| 22 | 2022-04-21 | 2021-04-21 | 4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-21 |
| 23 | 2022-04-26 | 2021-04-26 | 4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-04-26 |
| 24 | 2022-05-01 | 2021-05-01 | 5 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-01 |
| 25 | 2022-05-06 | 2021-05-06 | 5 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-06 |
| 26 | 2022-05-11 | 2021-05-11 | 5 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-11 |
| 27 | 2022-05-16 | 2021-05-16 | 5 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-16 |
| 28 | 2022-05-21 | 2021-05-21 | 5 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-21 |
| 29 | 2022-05-26 | 2021-05-26 | 5 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-05-26 |

Your logic is asking "is the current date in the month of January", at which point take the prior year, and then date truncate to the year, otherwise take the current date and truncate to the year. As the start of a BETWEEN test.

This is the same as getting the current date subtracting one month, and truncating this to year.

Thus there is no need for any IFF or CASE

```sql
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(year, DATEADD(month,-1, CURRENT_DATE())) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

and if you like to drop some paren's, `CURRENT_DATE` can be used if you leave it in upper case, thus it can even be smaller:

```sql
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(year, DATEADD(month,-1, CURRENT_DATE)) AND CURRENT_DATE
```